# approximate string matching in matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, signal-processing

Suppose that I have two small (A) and very large strings (B). I want to find the match strings of A in B, but I am not interested to exact match. In other words, I want to consider a threshold to find the match string. Therefore, in this case, I accept the strings that 2-3 elements of A are not exactly matched with the selected strings in B. So, my question is that how I can consider this approximation in matlab? Because, as I know, most of the string matching codes in matlab just find the exact match.

Furthermore, I want that it yields a bunch of strings instead of just one match. For example, it should provides, let say 10 strings, that are match with A with for example 2-3 mismatched.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you want something like the Smith-Waterman (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm) algorithm, which is implemented in the Bioinformatics Toolbox.

If that doesn't do exactly what you want, you could probably write your own matching routine somewhat inefficiently by comparing A with substrings of B using the Levenshtein distance.  There are several packages for the Levenshtein distance on Matlab Central (e.g., https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17585-calculation-of-distance-between-strings).